# Views retain the old database name from copied database

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I use the operation "Copy database to" in phpadmin the views in the newly created database retain the name from the old database.
Example: **`olddb`**.`table`.`column` -> **`oldbd`**.`table`.`column` instead of **`olddb`**.`table`.`column` -> **`newdb`**.`table`.`column`

Am I missing on something? Is there some setting that should be changed?
Currently I have it set pretty much close to the default

```
-CREATE DATABASE before copying
-Add AUTO_INCREMENT value
-Add constraints
-Adjust privileges
```